# Copy files while skipping over files that exist - Unix

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

I'd like to take a large folder (~100GB) and copy it over to another folder. I'd like it to skip any files that exist (not folders) so if `/music/index.html` does not exist it would still copy even though the `/music` directory already exists.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/118781/copy-files-in-linux-avoid-the-copy-if-files-do-exist-in-destination), but my shell is saying `-u` is not a valid argument.

I don't know how `rsync` works, so please let me know if that's a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: `rsync` is *always* the better solution. Yes, it's *that* good.

Comment: This question should probably be moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Always use `rsync` for copying files, because It Is Great.

To ignore existing files:

```
rsync --ignore-existing --recursive /src /dst
```

Do read the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) and search around for many, many great examples. Especially the combination with ssh makes `rsync` a great tool for slow and unreliable connections on account of its `--partial` option. Add `--verbose` to see which files are being copied. Be sure to check out the plethora of options concerning preservation of permissions, users and timestamps, too.

Comment: Is that recursive or do I need to add `-r`?

Comment: Perfectly, already up and running. I can tell it works by running in verbose mode (`-v`). Thanks!

Comment: To show progress while rsync works use:  

`rsync --human-readable --progress --ignore-existing --recursive  /src /dst`

Answer (score 8):

`rsync(1)` absolutely shines when the source and destination are on two different computers. It is still the better tool to use when the source and destination are on the same computer.

A *simple* use would look like:

```
rsync -av /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

If you're confident that any files that exist in both locations are identical, then use the `--ignore-existing` option:

```
rsync -av --ignore-existing /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Just for completeness, when I use `rsync(1)` to make a backup on a remote system, the command I most prefer is:

```
rsync -avz -P /path/to/source hostname:/path/to/destination
```

The `-z` asks for compression (I wouldn't bother locally, but over a slower network link it can make a big difference) and the `-P` asks for `--partial` and `--progress` -- which will re-use *partial* file transfers if it must be restarted, and will show a handy progress bar indicator.